# Containers dependency with etcd keys

Tags: docker, coreos, etcd, fleet

I want to have containers dependency with etcd keys.
Let's say I have a key "key" with value of "x", if that key changes to "y", I want to kill a specific container (which will automaticlly restart because it have a unit with always restart).
I'm not really sure how to achieve this.

This is because if some keys change, I need to start a chain of actions to restart few container (in a specific order).

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

You'll have to write some software to do this to encode your specific ruleset. This could be as simple as a bash script that is looping over `etcdctl` (or curl) and `systemctl`, or a Go program thats communicating with systemd over dbus.

Docs on [Waiting for a change on an etcd key](https://coreos.com/etcd/docs/latest/api.html#waiting-for-a-change).

Comment: Thank you, I will take a look. Maybe someone knows of something ready or some kind of tool for it?